# Jquery validate não valida corretamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

Estou usando Jquery validate e unobtrusive para validação em um projeto asp.net mvc 5

Quando precisei mexer com números decimais, em procura achei esse [Link](http://cleytonferrari.com/validacao-de-data-e-moeda-asp-net-mvc-jquery-validation-em-portugues/) aonde tem as validações e etc.

Mas estou com o seguinte problema:

Se eu deixo meu Bundle assim:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                        "~/Scripts/methods_pt.js"));
```

Ele funciona corretamente meus campos Decimais, mas ele para de remover as msg do ValidationMessageFor ao preencher os outros campos corretamente das outras validações(required por exemplo)

E se eu deixo assim:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/methods_pt.js"));
```

Ele funciona minhas validações mas não funciona a validação dos decimais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uso assim:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",                        
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"));
```

O problema do decimal não tem nada a ver com o jQuery Validate, e sim que está faltando o Globalize:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation.Globalize/

Comment: Funcionou, mas é como eu expliquei, ele não "remove" as msg do ValidationMessageFor ao preencher os campos de forma correta

Comment: Esse é o comportamento normal do `jquery.validate`. Vou procurar na documentação se tem uma maneira de esconder as messages dos campos corretos, aí atualizo na resposta.

Comment: Deve ser do unobstrusive então, pois é como eu expliquei, se ficar invertido ele faz o que comentei