# Validar Datetime no cliente

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

Tenho um model com uma propriedade do tipo `DateTime`:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Data em formato inválido")]
public DateTime? Date {get;set;}
```

E na `View`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
```

Ao se digitar uma data com o seguinte valor: 11/11/1111, é o valor não o formato, e mando o POST, ele passa no `ModelState`, mas no `SaveChange` ocasiona erro:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

O que tenho feito até agora e não obtive sucesso:

1 - No meu `Web.config` o seguinte atributo:

```
 <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

2 - Instalação do `jQuery` `globalize` e `jQuery Validate` `globalize`.
A ordem de carregamento é essa:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/libs/jquery.globalize/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/libs/jquery.globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.pt-BR.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/libs/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js"></script>
```

3 - Tratamento de número e datas utilizando `jQuery Validate` + `globalize`, com o seguinte código:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    date: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
    },
    number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

Qual a forma de validar essa entrada de data ou criar um "range" no cliente e não no server?

Comment: Por mais idiota que seja, tive um problema semelhante que se resolveu trocando de @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date)
para @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa pois é, mas eu utilizo TextBoxFor por causa do meu plugin do datepicker...usando EditorFor não funciona..

Comment: Alias, ele até abre o meu datepicker, mas aí abre também o do Html5 e não seta os valores com o meu datepicker, rs

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa na verdade kkk usando o datepicker do próprio html5 piora a situação, ele não aceita nem o formato que eu passo, sempre falando o campo .. deve ser uma data

Comment: @Rod Qual o valor definido na data antes do `SaveChanges`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez na pergunta tem o valor, que é 11/11/1111, sei que é meio improvavel, mas é que sempre tem um usuário que quer preencher para teste tudo com 11 ou valor único 22...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rod, o seu problema aqui não é validação do `Type DateTime`, mas sim o Range permitido pelo tipo `DateTime` no `SqlServer`.

Para resolver este problema, você pode mudar o tipo da coluna no SqlServer para `datetime2(7)`, que inclusive é o tipo recomendado para novas Tabelas.

Ou você pode colocar um DataAnnotations para validar o Range, de forma a ficar semelhante ao do SqlServer

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage="Isto não é um data")]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "01/01/1753", "31/12/9999")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: Fiz uma convention que todo datetime gera datetime2 obrigado era isso mesmo

Answer (score 1):

### O problema no .NET

A tradução de:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Seria algo como:

> A conversão do tipo de data "datetime2" para "datetime" resultou em um valor fora do intervalo/alcance.

O intervalo deve ser igual ou maior que "Janeiro 1, 1753" conforme o [msdn Date and Time Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx).

> These data types only support dates that occur after the introduction of the Gregorian calendar in England in 1753.
>
> PT: Estes dados suportam apenas datas que ocorrem após a introdução do calendário Gregoriano na Inglaterra em 1753.

### Validação no front-end:

Vou supor que em `11/11/1111` seja `dia/mes/ano`, padrão usado no Brasil, o código deve ficar algo como:

```
date: function (value, element) {
    var data, dataObjeto, ano;

    if (this.optional(element) || /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(value)) {
        data       = value.split("/");
        dataObjeto = new Date(data[2], data[1] - 1, data[0]);
        ano        = dataObjeto.getFullYear();

        return (
            ano == data[2] &&
            dataObjeto.getMonth() === parseInt(data[1]) &&
            dataObjeto.getDate() === parseInt(data[0]) &&
            ano > 1900 && ano < 2100
        );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Vou explicar o código:

- `data = value.split("/");` divide o data que é uma string
- `dataObjeto = new Date(data[2], data[1] - 1, data[0]);`, `data[2]` é o ano, `data[1]` o mês e `data[0]` o dia, assim o construtor `new Date` irá poder fazer o comparativo se a data é "valida".
- `ano == data[2]` verifica se o ano do `value` é igual ao ano que o `new Date` "entendeu", se for diferente é por que a data foi reajustada e o usuário provavelmente colocou um valor errado ou aleatório.
- `dataObjeto.getMonth() === parseInt(data[1])` compara se o mês foi o mesmo que recebido pelo `value`.
- `dataObjeto.getDate() === parseInt(data[0])` compara se o dia foi o mesmo que recebido pelo `value`.
- `ano > 1900` e `ano < 2100` é o seu intervalo/range permitido, você pode alterar.

Neste código se o usuário adicionar uma data como está `29/02/2015` (não é ano bissexto, portanto não existe dia 29) o `new Date` irá gerar está data `2015-03-01T03:00:00.000Z` (1 de Março de 2015), portanto a data inserida pelo usuário é inválida e o validador fica em `false`

Acaso o campo apresentar hora e data:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm}")]
```

Você pode usar a validação a *RegEx* assim:

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}[:]\d{2}$/
```

E o código deve ficar assim:

```
date: function (value, element) {
    "use strict";
    var horaData, data, hora, dataObjeto, ano;

    if (this.optional(element) || /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}[:]\d{2}$/.test(value)) {
        horaData = value.split(" ");

        data = horaData[0].split("/");
        hora = horaData[1].split(":");

        dataObjeto = new Date(data[2], data[1] - 1, data[0], hora[0], hora[1]);
        ano = dataObjeto.getFullYear();

        return (
            ano === parseInt(data[2]) &&
            dataObjeto.getMinutes() === parseInt(hora[1]) &&
            dataObjeto.getHours() === parseInt(hora[0]) &&
            dataObjeto.getMonth() === parseInt(data[1]) - 1 &&
            dataObjeto.getDate() === parseInt(data[0]) &&
            ano > 1900 && ano < 2100
        );
    }
    return false;
},
```

Comment: Olá @Guilherme,obrigado por responder, eu sei qual é o erro, é a tipagem que está no banco de dados, minha pergunta está relacionada, a como validar esse erro, mais precisamente na View

Comment: @Rod eu editei, agora me atentei a sua pergunta.

Comment: e quando for um campo de datetime mas que seja apresentado data e hora, acho q desse jeito não vai aceitar....

Comment: @rbrock Modifiquei a resposta, veja se o exemplo lhe ajuda.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento quase... editei ali com o que achei pertitente... verifica por favor... aqui funcionou... ;) (Y)

Answer (score 0):

O roteiro de resolução está em duas respostas que já escrevi:

- [Problema ao armazenar valores decimais no SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41975/problema-ao-armazenar-valores-decimais-no-sql-server/42017#42017)
- [Jquery validate não valida corretamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33072/jquery-validate-n%C3%A3o-valida-corretamente/33075#33075)

Comment: eu possuo o globalize de forma correta, e também o culture no Web.config principal(não os da areas) e ainda ocasiona o erro que citei

Comment: Instalou os JS?

Comment: Sim, essa mesma lib do nuget que está no link

Comment: Bem, posso estar falando bobagem, mas o erro não se refere à conversão na hora de tentar gravar na base de dados? O campo da tabela não estaria no formato yyyy/mm/dd???

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo Penso que é isso mesmo. Em teoria é alguma coisa no formato apenas na hora de gravar.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez , penso a mesma coisa pela mensagem de erro. Já me aconteceu coisa parecida e fiquei procurando problema onde não existia, até perceber o detalhe... Mas não sei se é o caso aqui.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo Ele fez a configuração se baseando em duas respostas minhas. Em teoria já devia estar funcionando.

Comment: Olá @CiganoMorrisonMendez *Se* a resolução está em duas resposta que você já escreveu, então isto não tornaria está atual questão uma duplicata?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mais ou menos. Creio que o problema não esteja descrito em nenhuma delas, a julgar pelo que foi colocado aqui até então. Estou com pouco tempo para ajudar agora.