# Erro ao salvar campo do tipo DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, crud, sql-server-2012, migrations

Estou montando um exemplo de Code First, mas na hora de salvar um campo do tipo DateTime no banco me retorna o seguinte erro

> A conversão de um tipo de dados datetime2 em um tipo de dados datetime
>   resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.\r\nA instrução foi finalizada.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>  em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator
>  ut)    em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T
>  noChangesResult, Func\`2 updateFunction)    em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()  
>  em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
>  em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func\`1
>  func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>  startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions
>  options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>  startLocalTransaction)    em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
>  em
>  System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>  operation)    em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions
>  options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)    em
>  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>  options)    em
>  System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
> ```

Isso acontece assim que chamo o `ctx.SaveChanges();`.

```
using Modelo.Classes.Banco;
using Modelo.Classes.Contexto;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace AppConsoleTestes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new dbContexto())
            {
                var usuario = new Usuarios();

                usuario.nomeUsuario = "Marconcilio das Virgens";
                usuario.senha = "123456";
                usuario.senhaTemp = true;
                usuario.ativo = true;
                usuario.bloqueado = false;
                usuario.dtInclusao = DateTime.Now;
                usuario.dtAdmissao = DateTime.Now;
                usuario.dtInclusao = DateTime.Now;

                ctx.Usuarios.Add(usuario);
                ctx.SaveChanges();


                var teste = ctx.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Minha classe no modelo;

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Modelo.Classes.Banco
{
    public class Usuarios
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 idUsuario { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(100)]
        public string nomeUsuario { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(2000)]
        public string obsUsuario { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string login { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string senha { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string telefone { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string celular { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(14)]
        public string cpf { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string nroMatricula { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtAdmissao { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtNascimento { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool senhaTemp { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool ativo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool bloqueado { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtInclusao { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] SeqAlteracao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Se eu comento os campo do tipo DateTime e altero o banco de dados com o DbMigration e mando salva não retorna o erro.

Não sei se estou fazendo algo errado ou esta faltando alguma coisa.

No banco de dados os tipo estão sendo criados com os tipo correto, a unica coisa que achei estranho foi a linha;

> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Usuarios] ADD  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000')
>   FOR

para cada campo do tipo datetime

```
USE [ControleOrcamentario]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Usuarios]    Script Date: 23/11/2016 16:59:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Usuarios](
    [idUsuario] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nomeUsuario] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [obsUsuario] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [login] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [senha] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [telefone] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [celular] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [cpf] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
    [nroMatricula] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [senhaTemp] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ativo] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bloqueado] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [dtAdmissao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [dtNascimento] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [dtInclusao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SeqAlteracao] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Usuarios] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idUsuario] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Usuarios] ADD  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000') FOR [dtAdmissao]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Usuarios] ADD  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000') FOR [dtNascimento]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Usuarios] ADD  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000') FOR [dtInclusao]
GO
```

Comment: são os tipos de dados no banco, são incompativeis pela configuração atual. No banco foi criado qual tipo de datetime?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, editei agora mesmo com isso, parece que esta gerando corretamente, só achei estranho o que ele faz com a declaração DEFAULT.

Comment: qual é o banco? e versão?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (Intel X86) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:13:17 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64)

Comment: Tente isso: `usuario.dtInclusao = DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: Tente isso também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51034/54880

Comment: Já tentou ver se o problema não é no campo `TimeStamp`? Isso aí ocorre quando você tenta salvar `null` numa coluna do tipo `datetime` que é NOT NULL.

Comment: @jbueno, já fiz um teste sem as colunas do tipo datetime e salvou nomalmente. resumindo não é o campo  [SeqAlteracao] [timestamp] NOT NULL, que esta causando o erro.

Comment: Bom eu já tive esse problema quando o SQLServer era 2008 tinha esse problema, mas, era no campo `datetime`

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Você tem certeza que o formato de datas do SQL Server é o mesmo do que do sistema operacional (ou definido na sua aplicação)?

Comment: @jbueno, isso eu não sei

Comment: Bom, então comece por aí @MarconcilioSouza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolve declarando o tipo no OnModelCreating();

Isso faz com que a tabela não crie a linha;

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Usuarios] ADD  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000') FOR [dtAdmissao]
GO
```

Esse valor `DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000')` , que estava quebrando meu código.

---

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios>()
       .Property(so => so.dtAdmissao)
       .HasColumnName("dtAdmissao")
       .HasColumnType("datetime");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios>()
      .Property(so => so.dtInclusao)
      .HasColumnName("dtInclusao")
      .HasColumnType("datetime");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios>()
      .Property(so => so.dtNascimento)
      .HasColumnName("dtNascimento")
      .HasColumnType("datetime");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Eu consegui resolver isso declarando uma annotations no campo data  :  ´[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]´

Comment: @WilliamCézar, isso criar no banco um campo do tipo datime ou DateTime2?

Answer (score -2):

Defina no annotations as datas que foram definidas com o DEFAULT de preenchimento no Banco de Dados

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]

public DateTime dtAdmissao { get; set; }